# Two query paramethers in @GET

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm doing a project, and i have to get data from an API using retrofit2.

My url is this: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search

After "search" i have a key (q) where is introduced the city name and a special word(queries), with the blank spaces being replaced by "+" sinal.
At the end of the key has to have "&format=json"
Here's the example on Postman:

[image: GetRequest on Postman]

Just one thing: usa+fuel it's just a demonstrative example. I need to search not only in the usa but around the whole world. In resumen the details of a location may be queried using the local_id from the local list returned in the following endpoint:
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details?place_id=194336640&format=json
replacing the place_id parameter with its id

The application should also facilitate the geospatial search of loading stations, ie, make the location of each station based on latitude and longitude available on the map. For the purpose
the nominatim API provides a service that translates GPS coordinates into addresses
(https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Lookup/)

How do i do this in android?

Comment: you want apiinterface for get request?

Comment: I want to know how my HEADERS(" ") and GET (" ") will be...

Comment: But yes, i'm creating an interface for get request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DYNAMIC URL With @Get in retrofit.

your interface is look like this:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET
Call<ModelName> getResponseUrl(@Url String url);
```

**Full Example code:**

**ApiInterface**:

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET
    Call<List<StreetMap>> getResponseUrl(@Url String url);
}
```

**Model-StreetMap.java**:

```
public class StreetMap {

    @SerializedName("place_id")
    @Expose
    private Long placeId;
    @SerializedName("licence")
    @Expose
    private String licence;
    @SerializedName("osm_type")
    @Expose
    private String osmType;
    @SerializedName("osm_id")
    @Expose
    private Long osmId;
    @SerializedName("boundingbox")
    @Expose
    private List<String> boundingbox = null;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private String lat;
    @SerializedName("lon")
    @Expose
    private String lon;
    @SerializedName("display_name")
    @Expose
    private String displayName;
    @SerializedName("class")
    @Expose
    private String _class;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("importance")
    @Expose
    private Double importance;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    @Expose
    private String icon;

    public Long getPlaceId() {
        return placeId;
    }

    public void setPlaceId(Long placeId) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
    }

    public String get_class() {
        return _class;
    }

    public void set_class(String _class) {
        this._class = _class;
    }

    public String getLicence() {
        return licence;
    }

    public void setLicence(String licence) {
        this.licence = licence;
    }

    public String getOsmType() {
        return osmType;
    }

    public void setOsmType(String osmType) {
        this.osmType = osmType;
    }

    public Long getOsmId() {
        return osmId;
    }

    public void setOsmId(Long osmId) {
        this.osmId = osmId;
    }

    public List<String> getBoundingbox() {
        return boundingbox;
    }

    public void setBoundingbox(List<String> boundingbox) {
        this.boundingbox = boundingbox;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getClass_() {
        return _class;
    }

    public void setClass_(String _class) {
        this._class = _class;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Double getImportance() {
        return importance;
    }

    public void setImportance(Double importance) {
        this.importance = importance;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

}
```

**APIClient.java:**

```
public class APIClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();


        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Activity code:**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ApiInterface apiInterface;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        String cityName="usa+fuel";
        Call<List<StreetMap>> callUrl = apiInterface.getResponseUrl("/search?q="+cityName+"&format=json");
        callUrl.enqueue(new Callback<List<StreetMap>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<StreetMap>> call, Response<List<StreetMap>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success Response",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<StreetMap>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error in Response:"+t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I'll try and see if it works
Rest of a good day!

Comment: I've updated my question cause i wasn't 100% cleared about what i really want. Your answer solved my inicial question, except the cityName field

Comment: I have read your question,You have different search,lookup,place_id end point.So you need to create different api interface for this.Because this api does not provide all place details from one api.

Comment: Ok, i'll do the other interface.

Comment: can i contact you privately? I think it's more simple to clarify my issue

Answer (score 0):

Your network call interface using retrofit with headers will come like this :

```
@Headers({
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "User-Agent: Your-App-Name",
    "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"
         })
@GET("search") 
Call<String> getData(@Query("q") String city_name,@Query("format") String format)
```

---

Comment: Many thanks! I'll try and see if it works
Rest of a good day!